# Kubuntu black screen after login

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, login, screen, tty

Im using clean install of Kubuntu 16.04 for 2 days, but today after login screen (SDDM) I got black screen, I can only use TTY. So everything looks like normal till login screen, after I click login my monitor turns black and I can only use TTY. I didn't install any drivers.

I tried:

- nomodeset
- deleting .config and .cache folders
- run `sudo startx` from TTY and I got an error: `timeout in locking authority file /home/tomsk/.Xauthority` and after that black screen shows in that current TTY (so I lost a terminal)

But none of that helped.

I tried to login with iGPU and GPU (NVIDIA) too but with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by deleting `.Xauthority` files in home directory.

Comment: Thanks, I tried everything possible but this solved the issue